# Is there an easy way to check if all elements in ICollection<ISet<string>> are identical?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of

```
<string, ISet<string>>
```

What I want to do is check if all the values in the dictionary are identical.

The only thing I can think of is iterating the dict.Values in a simple for and check. But is there any workaround using LINQ or something else?

Comment: If you take a look at LINQ methods it shouldn't be hard to find an appropriate one. Something with `Distinct()`.

Comment: All the values in the `ISet`, or all sets in the `Dictionary`?

Comment: @hvd all the values in Dictionary*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ISet<String> firstSet = dic.Values.FirstOrDefault(); 

bool sameSets = (firstSet == null) ||
                dic.Values.Skip(1).All(set => set.SequenceEqual(firstSet));
```

Should do it

Basically getting the first set and then comparing each set with it.

(`Dictionary<string, ISet<string>>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISet<string>>>`)

Note that nothing constrains an `ISet<T>` to enumerate in a specific order so you might need to sort `firstSet` and `set`.

Or

```
bool sameSets = (firstSet == null) ||
                dic.Values.Skip(1).All(set => 
                  (set.Count == firstSet.Count) && 
                  set.All(setItem => firstSet.Contains(setItem));
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted. thanks a lot! working like charm